# Locally symmetric spaces: spectrum of the Laplacian

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, eigenvalues, laplacian

Let $M = \Gamma\backslash X$ denote a locally symmetric space of non-compact type and $\Delta$ the Laplacian on $L^2(M)$.

It is known that the spectrum of $\Delta$ decomposes into finitely many 
eigenvalues $0=\lambda_0 < ... <\lambda_r < a^2$ and a continuous part $[a^2,\infty)$. The continous part $[a^2,\infty)$ contains further eigenvalues.

If $X$ is a hyperbolic space, $a^2 = 1/4$.

The Selberg-1/4-conjecture states that for Hilbert-Modular-Surfaces the only eigenvalue < 1/4 is $\lambda_0 = 0$.

Does anybody know concrete examples of locally symmetric spaces (or more specifically where $X$ is a hyperbolic space or at least is a symmetric space with $\mathbb{Q}$-rank = 1) where there exist further eigenvalues (apart from 0) below the continuous part of the spectrum?

Thanks!

Comment: The only examples I've seen of surfaces with small Laplacian eigenvalues are discussed in Sarnak's survey article "Spectra of Hyperbolic Surfaces". But I don't think any of Sarnak's examples are what you have in mind.

Comment: That does not seem possible if one looks at theorem 1.2 in this(DOI 10.1007/s00222-012-0415-2) paper of Bergeron-Clozel.